# Create a 2-D numpy array with list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create a 2-D numpy array using only list comprehension, but it has to follow the following format:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [5, 6, 7]]]
```

So far, all I've managed to figure out is:

```
two_d_array = np.array([[x+1 for x in range(3)] for y in range(5)])
```

Giving:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Just not very sure how to change the incrementation. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Accidentally left out [3, 4, 5] in example. Included it now.

Comment: Try `x + y` instead of `x + 1`

Comment: Where is `[3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: @ForceBru perhaps `x + y + 1` instead of `x + 1`

Comment: is the line `[3,4,5]` missing from your desired array or is it intentionally removed?

Comment: Sorry, [3, 4, 5] was left out by mistake.

Comment: Do you need to use a list comprehension? Could use `[1, 2, 3] + np.arange(5)[:, None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick one-liner that will do the job:

```
np.array([np.arange(i, i+3) for i in range(1, 6)])
```

Where `3` is the number of columns, or elements in each array, and `6` is the number of iterations to perform - or in this case, the number of arrays to create; which is why there are 5 arrays in the output.

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Still getting used to all the different np functions. This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the code, something like this can work:

```
two_d_array = np.array([[(y*3)+x+1 for x in range(3)] for y in range(5)])
>>> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...]
two_d_array = np.array([[y+x+1 for x in range(3)] for y in range(5)])
>>> [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of good comprehension answers, so here are a couple of numpy solutions.

Simple addition:

```
np.arange(1, 6)[:, None] + np.arange(3)
```

Crazy stride tricks:

```
base = np.arange(1, 8)
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(base, shape=(5, 3), strides=base.strides * 2).copy()
```

Reshaped cumulative sum:

```
base = np.ones(15)
base[3::3] = -1
np.cumsum(base).reshape(5, 3)
```

Comment: @S3DEV. Fixed the -1. Where are you getting 9 from the question?